# NSException with launching main file

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode13

I am a new programmer for Swift. I followed a tutorial to get a little setup, but then most of the other coding I did myself. I am a long time python programmer, and I am a little lost on the errors I am getting. I removed a few files from the project for IP reasons, but I cannot get the program even started on my phone. The project is located [here][1]. I cannot seem to figure out the startup sequence for xcode 13.

I am using XCode 13, Swift 4.2, and several other items. Here is the error I am getting when I push the compiled code to my phone.

2022-02-15 15:43:03.321402-0600 FirebaseStarterApp[3090:1225786] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38489EE8-9C77-4334-83DD-C0D1798CBCEC/FirebaseStarterApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow.xib''
*** First throw call stack:

(0x1810690fc 0x1998b5d64 0x1810c0230 0x1839b2260 0x184061ea8 0x1843cb21c 0x1835adba0 0x1839722a8 0x1837cf940 0x183627af0 0x183753438 0x183874104 0x183ab52f8 0x183a40818 0x1836288f4 0x1836e9160 0x18362a804 0x183715448 0x183b9d5cc 0x18365913c 0x18369ca50 0x1837d486c 0x183713708 0x192ccc8d4 0x192cf2824 0x192cad06c 0x192cae6ac 0x106c1e3b4 0x106c21e70 0x192cae9c4 0x192cadd8c 0x192cb2414 0x18108b0d0 0x18109bd90 0x180fd6104 0x180fdb8a4 0x180fef468 0x19cb8f38c 0x1839925d0 0x183710f74 0x104bda70c 0x105365aa4)

libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38489EE8-9C77-4334-83DD-C0D1798CBCEC/FirebaseStarterApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow.xib''
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Any help is greatly appreciated, I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is not working.

Comment: It seems like the project you uploaded is missing some files which are preventing it from compiling. (for example, LandingScreen is referenced but its Swift file is not present).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Info.plist entry for main nib was not needed. Removed and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).